# Rcpp subsetting contiguous StringVector

Tags: subset, rcpp, contiguous

Good afternoon,

I have been trying to use a similar method to subsetting `x[200:300]` in R while using Rcpp. (Note, this is not the problem I am trying to solve, but I need to subset many ranges within the functions I am trying to write in C++, and I found that this was the bottleneck of my performance)

However, although I have tried ussing the methods in rcpp, using iterators or other things, I just don't seem to find a solution that is minimally "fast." Most of the solutions I find are very slow.

And looking at the reference of Rcpp, I can't seem to find anything, not can I find it looking in StackExchange.

I know this code is pretty ugly right now... But I am just clueless

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
StringVector range_test_( StringVector& x, int i, int j){
    StringVector vect(x.begin()+i, x.begin()+j);
    return vect;
}
```

And then, it is like 800 times slower. I have been trying to find the same `x[i:j]` function that R, which is very fast, within the rcpp base... but I can't find it.

```
 tests_range <- rbenchmark::benchmark(
    x[200:3000],
    range_test_(x, 200, 3000),
    order = NULL,
    replications = 80
)[,1:4]
```

Gives as result

```
                             test replications elapsed relative
1                     x[200:3000]           80   0.001        1
3       range_test_(x, 200, 3000)           80   0.822      822
```

If anybody knows how to access the subsetting function `x[i:j]` or something as fast within Rcpp I would really appreciate it. I just can't seem to find the tool I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the iterator constructor makes a copy. See [this page](http://yixuan.cos.name/rcpp-note/api/Vector_ctor.html#_CPPv2N6Vector6VectorE13InputIterator13InputIterator)

> Copy the data between iterators first and last to the created vector

However, you can try this instead

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::StringVector in_range(Rcpp::StringVector &x, int i, int j) {
  return x[Rcpp::Range(i - 1, j - 1)]; // zero indexed
}
```

The time taken is a lot closer

```
> set.seed(20597458)
> x <- replicate(1e3, paste0(sample(LETTERS, 5), collapse = ""))
> head(x)
[1] "NHVFQ" "XMEOF" "DABUT" "XKTAZ" "NQXZL" "NPJLM"
> 
> stopifnot(all.equal(in_range(x, 100, 200), x[100:200]))
> 
> library(microbenchmark)
> microbenchmark(in_range(x, 100, 200), x[100:200], times = 1e4)
Unit: nanoseconds
                  expr  min   lq     mean median   uq     max neval
 in_range(x, 100, 200) 1185 1580 3669.780   1581 1976 3263205 10000
            x[100:200]  790  790 1658.571   1185 1186 2331256 10000
```

Note that there is a [page here](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/subsetting/) on susbetting. I could not find a relevant example there though.

Comment: Oh damn,I just noticed why it was so much slower. I was inputting numeric vectors, and Rcpp was having to convert them and output string vectors when doing the testing.

Comment: That explain the very large relative difference. I assume that the solution I provide is faster as you avoid the copy if I am correct.

Comment: Using pointers turns out to be 10% faster to the range method. I did the proper test with 30000 long vectors, and selecting 20000 of them. And they are better than the  R subsetting.

Comment: Should I keep this question, now that I noticed the error, or should I add my own reply? In case someone finds this at some point. Thank you for your time anyway Benjamin

Comment: Looking into the source code I think it would be better to use `R_xlen_t` instead of `int` for the `i` and `j` argument: https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/master/inst/include/Rcpp/sugar/Range.h#L29

Comment: `i` and `j` are also not validated against the vector size which could access memory outside of the vector...

Comment: Yes, using `R_xlen_t` is a better alternative depending on how R is build (https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/d4ae16face4416942dac5abaf840a2372e2d4e3a/src/include/Rinternals.h#L71-L78). No there is no bounds checks. Use the `operator()` member function if you want bound checks (http://yixuan.cos.name/rcpp-note/api/Vector_funs.html#_CPPv2clRK6size_t). It seems like the OP wanted something fast so I went for the `operator[]` member function instead.

Comment: @BenjaminChristoffersen I just wanted to "warn" users of the code snippet about risks. Yes, bracket and parens operators do support bounds checking but they don't operate on a range which makes them "slower". BTW I love your answer, it seems to be the only one I could find on how to subset a vector using an index range! I have proposed to use your script to extend the Rcpp gallery...